# Carthage update takes forever and I don't use but two of the services at the moment

Tags: ibm-watson, carthage

Is there some way I can just use a portion of the watson ios sdk?  Carthage update downloads and builds about 10+ services that I'm not using and the "All Services" build takes forever.
Is there a way I can cut down the time and specify only the services I use in my app?
(I'm guessing no, but it sure would be nice!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for mentioning the hassle you've experienced with the build process, @troyd. It's always good to hear from users, whether for better or for worse--it really helps us to identify and prioritize issues.

The Carthage build process has definitely been a major pain point with the [Watson Developer Cloud iOS SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/ios-sdk), and we've been trying to improve it for some time. I think it's gotten better with recent releases.

Can you try using the v0.7.0 release (for Xcode 7 / Swift 2.2) or v0.8.0 release (for Xcode 8 / Swift 2.3)? We removed the "All Services" target and started including binaries with each GitHub release.

I'd love to hear your thoughts on the build process with one of the newer releases. It should be much faster, since it will only build the dependencies (Alamofire, Freddy, Starscream) then download the Watson frameworks.

Unfortunately, there is no way to choose the services to build short of separating each service into its own repository (which isn't on the roadmap right now).

Comment: Thanks Glenn.  I noticed when building with 0.8.0 that the binaries were being pulled and therefore cut down my build time tremendously (thanks for that).  Didn't realize the binaries weren't provided for 0.6 and that's the reason for the build - and that there was an All Services target.  Problem solved.  :)

Comment: Great! Glad to hear it. :)

Comment: with release 0.9.1 doesn't include the binaries so we are forced to build all the APIs even if we only use a few.


*** Building scheme "PersonalityInsightsV2" in WatsonDeveloperCloud.xcodeproj
*** Building scheme "AlchemyVisionV1" in WatsonDeveloperCloud.xcodeproj
*** Building scheme "NaturalLanguageClassifierV1" in WatsonDeveloperCloud.xcodeproj
*** Building scheme "DialogV1" in WatsonDeveloperCloud.xcodeproj
*** Building scheme "AlchemyLanguageV1" in WatsonDeveloperCloud.xcodeproj
*** Building scheme "SpeechToTextV1" in WatsonDeveloperCloud.xcodeproj

Comment: Thanks for the message @troyd. This got a bit complicated with recent releases of Xcode, since Xcode 8.1 uses Swift 3.0.1, and Swift 3.0.1 binaries are not compatible with Swift 3.0. We wanted to publish the release, but take some time to consider which version to post (since some users will have issues if we post the wrong version). We'll probably publish the Swift 3.0.1 binaries and update the readme next week.

Comment: Ugh.. Apple isn't making this easy at all.

Comment: too bad we can't tell carthage which targets in the xcodeproj to build.

Comment: Agreed. We did release [v0.10.0](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/ios-sdk/releases/tag/v0.10.0) and included the binaries for Xcode 8.1 / Swift 3.0.1.